# Get PHP Array contents into Table (or DIV)

Tags: php, html, arrays, bash

I am using shell_exec to grab some bash line output. This is returned as text like:

```
22/tcp  open   ssh
80/tcp  open   http
153/tcp closed unknown
443/tcp open   https
```

I then create an array using preg_split using **'/\s+/'** to split on whitespace and newline, echo'ing the array gets:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 22/tcp
    [1] => open
    [2] => ssh
    [3] => 80/tcp
    [4] => open
    [5] => http
    [6] => 153/tcp
    [7] => closed
    [8] => unknown
    [9] => 443/tcp
    [10] => open
    [11] => https
)
```

I would like to be able to put these values into a 3 column table (or even better a collection of DIVs) that expands as the data set expands (so loop for whatever n lines returned from bash output). How do I go about getting the above array into a table/div where the rows in this example would looks something like:

```
 ____________________________
| 22/tcp  |  open  |   ssh   |
| 80/tcp  |  open  |   http  |
| 153/tcp | closed | unknown |
| 443/tcp |  open  |  https  |
```

Comment: Can I ask whoever it was why my question was downvoted? A little harsh for a valid and decently constructed question don't you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a quick for loop:

```
for ( $i = 0, $len = count($array); $i < $len; $i += 3)
{
    echo '<tr>
              <td>' . $array[$i] . '</td>
              <td>' . $array[$i+1] . '</td>
              <td>' . $array[$i+2] . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

You can see it in action [here](https://3v4l.org/sW0jG).

You can also use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to get your desired result as well:

```
foreach ( array_chunk($array, 3) as $chunk )
{
    echo '<tr>
              <td>' . $chunk[0] . '</td>
              <td>' . $chunk[1] . '</td>
              <td>' . $chunk[2] . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

You can see it in action [here](https://3v4l.org/8Uo9a).

Comment: Thankyou, that works perfectly. Not sure why I overlooked the obvious there.... It's been a long day. Thanks. (I will accept answer once timer allows me)

Comment: @DaveByrne I posted an alternate solution as well

Comment: add `htmlentities($chunk[X], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);`
 encoding so they're valid html :)